# Strange behavior in Kotlin For-Loops

Tags: kotlin

Today I found a strange behavior when using For-Loops:

`daysToPrepend = 6`
`daysToAppend = 5`

For these two for loops I get different outputs:

Case 1:

```
for (day in 0..daysToPrepend) {
    Log.i("APP_TEST", day.toString())
}

for (day in 0..daysToAppend) {
    Log.i("APP_TEST", day.toString())
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Case 2:

```
for (day in 0..daysToPrepend) {
    Log.i("APP_TEST", "Loop1")
}

for (day in 0..daysToAppend) {
    Log.i("APP_TEST", "Loop2")
}
```

Output:

```
Loop1
Loop1
Loop2
Loop2
```

What is going on here? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It works correctly at my computer, can you share your full logcat?

Comment: The logcat collapses identical lines. You should see some indication that it is happening.

Comment: Oh my god - Sorry for the stupid question